# ink-e2e: Metadata artifacts not generated when importing crate

Tags: ink, smart-contract, testing, openbrush

###### Context:

I am trying to detach end-to-end tests from my main contract `lib.rs`. I created a new module in `tests_e2e.rs`.

I import the module in main contract like so:

###### `lib.rs`...vvv

```rust
#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
mod tests_e2e;
```

In the `tests_e2e.rs` file, I have the usual module defined for ink_e2e  tests, but with the obvious addition of the crate import (named `ilockmvp`):

###### `tests_e2e.rs`...vvv

```rust
    pub mod e2e_tests {

        use crate::ilockmvp::*;

        use ink_e2e::{
            build_message,
            CallResult,
        };
        use openbrush::contracts::psp22::psp22_external::PSP22;
        use ink::primitives::{
            Clear,
            Hash,
        };
```

When I build test with `cargo +nightly test --features e2e-tests -- --show-output` I get this error:
[image: error results]

When I remove the crate import, no such error occurs, but the obvious error that I need to import things ensues.

###### Question:

How do I work around this? --thoughts/suggestions/insights?

***** I got this working fine for my `#[ink::test]` unit tests in a different module file (`tests_unit.rs`).

Answer (score 1):

In short:

1. Create a separate file (e.g. `e2e_tests.rs`) and move all the code from e2e_tests module there (without mod e2e_tests).
2. Add these lines on top of `e2e_tests.rs` file:

```
use crate::<your_crate_name>::*;

#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
pub use ink_e2e::build_message;
```

3. In `lib.rs` add:

```
#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
pub mod e2e_tests;
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1692#issuecomment-1448643351

Issue already submitted.

The only solution I have found for now is to save both the file containing the e2e_tests and the one containing the contract with each modification (without performed cargo clean) and this works for me.

Comment: Ok yeah, the double-save method works for me. Thanks! Apparently the issue has been fixed though? I do not understand how to make their fix apply to my usecase.

Comment: yes can confirm, now is fixed .

Comment: to apply the fix just use the new ink release :)

Comment: `cargo clean` works for me

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in this contract is separate `ink_e2e` test to different folder. You can [`view`](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/decode-ink-events) in this gh repo. I compiled and it works fine.

Comment: If you run the e2e tests with your example it gives the same error

Comment: but I am not getting error look in this image https://github.com/ganesh1233456/decode-ink-events/blob/main/Screenshot%202023-02-28%20at%2021.50.10.png

Comment: @Ganesh11 you're running test with stable contract channel. I have to use `+nightly` because they use this `#![feature(min_specialization)]`. Your example will pass the same error running with `+nightly` unfortunately.

Also, @DaanvanderPlas, I followed your example to the letter and no luck, same error. I also stripped out everything in the test to that it was just a naked `#[ink_e2e::test]` instance.

I wonder if it is something to do the the `+nightly` toolchain? My version is `1.69.0-nightly`. What are yours'?

Comment: @blairmunroakusa `rustc 1.69.0-nightly (c5c7d2b37 2023-02-24)`

Answer (score 0):

###### Steps to recreate problem:

- Set up tests_e2e.rs module as specified by @DaanvanderPlas answer above.
  This configuration is correct, but will not necessarily solve the problem once the damage is done.
- Remove `#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]` from the module file.
- Attempt to build and run tests with `+nightly` will fail with OP error message, consisting of the first e2e test failed to generate metadata artifacts, then one 'Once instance has previously been poisoned' message per remaining e2e test.
- Attempt to replace `#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]` in `tests_e2e.rs` module file should continue to fail and produce the same set of error messages.

###### Additional steps (beyond @DaanvanderPlas setup) to solve problem:

- Delete `target` directory or `cargo clean` and build and run test from scratch.

And that's it, should work again.

...

In @Ganesh11's example repo, building and running test with stable `cargo contract v2.0.0` will still succeed if the macro is left out in the tests module file. However, running with `+nightly v0.69.0` will fail without the second instance of the ink_e2e macro. And, once it has failed, `target` will need to be deleted or run `cargo clean`.

The reason for needing `+nightly` in this scenario is because Openbrush contracts rely on the `#![feature(min_specialization)]` macro, which is not supported by the stable toolchain.

###### EDIT!!!

- This issue not only comes up if removing the ink_e2e cfg macro. Any change to the tests_e2e.rs file in general causes this problem, and a cargo clean must be performed.
- This is a big problem because the build time is so long.